# php part of wordpress module

Tags: php, wordpress, module

somebody has made a module, now i have to change it but I don't understand exactly what he wrote. Is $dnssec the var that i give the value? And what does the if statement with the echo "selected"?

```
<tr>
        <th>DNSSEC:</th>
        <td>
            <select name="domeinnaam_extensies_dnssec">
                <option value="Ja" <?php
                    if ($dnssec == "Ja") {
                        echo "selected";
                    }
                    ?>>Ja</option>
                <option value="Nee" <?php
                    if ($dnssec == "Nee") {
                        echo "selected";
                    }
                    ?>>Nee</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just basically setting the selected option of your select.

So, `$dnssec` is a variable which is initiated somewhere before your current code.

The `if` statement is used to check whether the variable `$dnssec` is equal to `Ja` or `Nee` which will return `true` or `false` and based on that condition, it'll set the selected option accordingly.

Comment: And what do how can I make a var to give it the value of the selection? He made everything like this and that works..

Comment: I don't get what you means. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: I can't explain it. And I can't post my code here on the right way, very annoying